# How do I use group by showing the newest row of data

Tags: mysql

Can someone please tell me how to use the group by clause, grouping by one of the keys in the table but yet having the newest timestamp at the top? I have multiple rows of data but I only want to show the newest row

Comment: Grouping by the primary key will have no effect as a primary key is by definition unique.

Comment: I know, I just edited my post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only the most recent one per group:

```
SELECT somefield
FROM table t1
WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp)
                   FROM table t2
                   WHERE t1.somefield = t2.somefield);
```

Or just the latest most recent one:

```
SELECT somefield
FROM table
GROUP BY somefield
ORDER BY MAX(timestamp) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help. I actually edited my post to reflect this change as I realized it after I had already posted. I have a FK that I am grouping on which still leaves me with a few rows. I need to limit that to the newest timestamp

Comment: Maybe add a "limit 1" and he will get just the one row he wants.

Comment: **@jabbie:** He wants the most recent one per group. A `LIMIT` won't help you there. My last example will achieve that.

Comment: Exactly. Thanks Andrew. I'm trying that now but for some reason I'm getting an empty set. :/

Comment: I havent actually selected the timestamp in my fields. Do I need that selected?

Comment: **@Jim:** I've edited my question, which should work better (I don't think you need a group by for what you want).

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I still can't get this to work though. I even tried your sub query but I don't need the where operator in there. All I want is the most recent row from that group, so if I have 5 total rows that have been rendered after the group by clause, then all I will need is the newest row from there ordered decending.

Comment: I think your having clause is what I need but I'm not 100% sure on this.

Comment: It won't work with the HAVING. Try the WHERE on the subquery.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I have a primary key in that table and just grouped by the newest number which gives me what I need. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT Foo.Bar, Foo.SomeTimestamp
FROM Foo
ORDER BY Foo.SomeTimestamp DESC
```

If you're grouping by a column, you're probably returning aggregate data. If the timestamp is unique for each row of aggregate data, you may need to use the `MAX` function (or the like) to return a single timestamp for each group. For example:

```
SELECT Foo.TypeID, SUM(Foo.Price) AS Price, MAX(Foo.OrderDate) AS LastOrder
FROM Foo
GROUP BY Foo.TypeID
ORDER BY MAX(Foo.OrderDate) DESC
```

---

If you only want the first row, you can use the `LIMIT` clause:

```
SELECT Foo.Bar, Foo.SomeTimestamp
FROM Foo
ORDER BY Foo.SomeTimestamp DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

This starts at row 0 and returns at most 1 row.